How in the world do I fix this anciently old slop sink? I am okay even with a temporary fix
I have tried to install a PVC P-Trap, but I couldn't get it to fit properly. Should I remove the pipe with the yellow rubber o ring? Please advise me, I would appreciate it kindly.
Pictures:




Get a sink P-trap kit. It has the trap and the horizontal piece to go into the wall adapter.  You will have to check to see if you have the 1 1/4 or 1 1/2 inch size. (Yes remove the old horizontal piece.Hopefully you have the nut.)
You may need a Sink drain extension. If the drain is too short to meet the new p-trap.
Everything is hand tight and should come with the washers you need.
